# What if I multiply fields that may no be defined?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework

In my aggregation pipeline, there will be stage where 2 fields are multiplied to create a new field.

What happens if 1 or both of the values for those particular fields are undefined for a document?

Comment: `null`. [Sample demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4FVWwPOQAue)

Comment: But you can use `$ifNull` if you want to override it. For example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/LVPHqf8QC9m